# DRF: token deleting in custom authentication not working

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-rest-auth

I use `djangorestframework` and `django-rest-auth` for authentification api. I want to use a `created` field of `rest_framework.authtoken.models.Token` for checking token expiration. So I need to delete an expired token after expires checking, but calling `delete()` method does not delete token object!

`settings.py`

```py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'rest_auth',
    ...
]

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'users.authentication.ExpirationAuth',
    ),

    'DEFAULT_THROTTLE_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.throttling.AnonRateThrottle',
        'rest_framework.throttling.UserRateThrottle'
    ),

    'DEFAULT_THROTTLE_RATES': {
        'anon': '50/hour',
        'user': '100/hour'
    }
}
```

`users.authentication.py`

```py
from rest_framework.authentication import TokenAuthentication, exceptions
from django.utils.timezone import get_current_timezone
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from config import constants

current_timezone = get_current_timezone()


class ExpirationAuth(TokenAuthentication):
    """ Custom authentication with expiration token """

    def authenticate_credentials(self, key):
        model = self.get_model()

        try:
            token = model.objects.get(key=key)

        except model.DoesNotExist:
            raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed('Invalid token.')

        if self.expired(token):
            token.delete()
            raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed('Token has expired.')

        if not token.user.is_active:
            raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed('User inactive or deleted.')

        return token.user, token

    @staticmethod
    def expired(token) -> bool:
        return token.created < (datetime.now(current_timezone) - timedelta(hours=constants.token_expiration_hours))
```

If the token has expired I get a message `Token has expired.`, but this token still in the database.

Comment: You're probably running into issues with how [Django handles transactions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/transactions/#tying-transactions-to-http-requests), you'll need to catch the authenticationfailed exception at a higher level and then return a proper response - if you let Django handle it, the transaction made by `.delete()` will probably be rolled back.

Comment: You`re right, thanks!